# REGEX conundrum

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help to get this selector with regex

The line to be processed:

> example frase for this conundrum this example frase has variable lengths but it ends in foobar

Expected result:

> example frase has variable lengths but it ends in foobar

I have to filter in the same line "conundrum" so that if it encounters "example frase" but it follows "conundrum" before "foobar" it doesn't select from the beginning, instead of selecting appropriately on the second "example frase"

Here's my closest approach:

> /(example frase).*(foobar)/

It lacks the negation of "conundrum" but I haven't find a good way to do that, this certainly didn't worked

> /(example frase).*(?!(conundrum)).*(foobar)/

Comment: Can you show your current Regex? It helps to provide code samples of what you have tried.

Comment: sure! I'll edit it

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down the question in to multiple parts, examine each part individually and then put them all back together.

In essence, the task can be reduced to the following set of rules:

Find all text that:

- starts with "example frase": `(\bexample frase\b)` -- this will deliberately avoid matching "example frases", "myexample frase", etc by endorsing phrase boundary with `\b`
- ends with "foobar": `(\bfoobar\b)` -- this avoids terminating the selection prematurely, for example on "foobarbaz"
- does not contain the word "conundrum": `(?!.*\bconundrum\b)` -- uses negative look ahead and defines the word boundary

Now putting it all together, the final regex looks like this:

```
/(\bexample frase\b)(?!.*\bconundrum\b).*(\bfoobar\b)/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative look-ahead:

```
/example frase(?!.+conundrum.+foobar).+/
```

[Regex101 Link](https://regex101.com/r/lKzg38/1)